# Show that the equation $y=e^x/x^3$ has a root between $1.2$ and $1.3$

Tags: newton-raphson

Show that the equation $y=e^x/x^3$ has a root between $1.2$ and $1.3$

Hey, having trouble with this one. Would appreciate a hand, not sure how to go about the exponent and such.

Comment: can you check whether you have typed the question correctly?

Comment: What do you mean?  As $x$ goes from $1.2$ to $1.3$, $e^x/x^3$ goes from approximately $1.92$ to approximately $1.67$.  Are you supposed to take some $y$ in that interval?

Comment: I typed the question correctly yes, @RobertIsrael I got those as well but im not sure if its right, as I read that to prove it has a root there needs to be a negative value? Im really new to this so I don't really have a clue, heres part B if it helps make sense.

Comment: Use the Newton-Raphson method to find the value of the root correct to seven significant figures.

Comment: There must be a mistake in the question, then.

Answer (score 2):

For $x>0$, $\frac{\exp(x)}{x^3} >0$, it is not a true statement.

For $x<0$, $\frac{exp(x)}{x^3} < 0$, it doesn't have a root.

The function is not defined at $x=0$.

It doesn't have a root.

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

Desmos link [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/heirp5ntdg).